# C# - Communicate between two projects without two-way references

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, events, delegates

I have two projects: Project A and and external Project B (added via "Add Existing Project in Visual Studio). Project A has a reference to Project B, but Project B does not have a reference to Project A. I have a WinForm Textbox in Project A that I would like Project B to be able to write text to. Because Project B doesn't have a reference to Project A, I can't call a method I created in Project A that adds text to the textbox.

My question: Is it possible to have Project B call that method or write to that Textbox **without** adding a project reference?

Comment: Not sure why you need a circular reference (which you can't)... Usually project A is the UI and project B is a class library. You should be able to call logic in project B from project A to render data. Other methods are APIs, shared db, etc. What is your specific use case?

Comment: Consider creating a new "common" Project with the winform you want to reuse within. This way project A and B can reference to this common Project. Another solution could be to use [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)

Comment: @LukeHutton Project A is the UI. Project A calls a constructor in Project B which starts some data processing - I would like to visually display the processing info to the user using the UI textbox in Project A. I'm working on an installer - the processing info from Project B would be displayed to let the user know what is currently being done.

Comment: Oh I see, use case makes it more clear. There are many ways to accomplish that. Instead of having project B being concerned with UI, it should really only do its work and report its current progress (separation of concerns). UI would listen on separate thread and update the view. See ```IProgress``` pattern for example http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress

Comment: Add `ProgressChanged` event in project `B`. Then just attach some logic to that event in project `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Circular references, while allowed in C#, are often a symptom of poor architecture decisions.  Is this possible?

```
void MyEventFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txt = MyClassFromB.GetStringFromB();
    textBox1.Text = txt;
}
```

Ideally, you'd want B's code to just give you the string you want when you need it, so A can control when it gets updated.

Alternatively, you can get delegates involved.

In B:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate void UpdateStringVar(string x);
    private UpdateStringVar usv;
    MyClass(UpdateStringVar v)
    {
        usv = v;
    } 

    void ContinuouslyRunningOperation()
    {
        string status = //get some string
        usv(status);
    }
}
```

In A:

```
void UpdateTextBox(string x)
{ 
    textBox1.Text = x;
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass(UpdateTextBox);
```

Something like this will work if your entire application is single threaded, but WinForms controls have that annoying "can only access this object from the thread that created it" requirement, so extra work will be required if your B code is running on a different thread.